# Maximal number of nonzero diagonals in a permutation matrix

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let $P = (p_{ij})_{0\leq i, j < n}$ be a $n \times n$ permutation matrix, i.e. each row and column has exactly one one and $(n-1)$ zeros.
Let $\mathbf{d}_k := (p_{0, k}, p_{1, k +1}, \dots, p_{n-1, k + n-1})$ be the $k$-th diagonal, which is an $n$-dimensional vector. Here the indices are regarded modulo $n$.

> Q1. What is $a_n := \max_{P \in S_n} \#\{0\leq k < n: \mathbf{d}_k \neq \mathbf{0}\}$, i.e. the maximum of the number of nonzero diagonals?

Obviously $a_n \leq n$. For odd $n$, we have $a_n = n$ by taking $P_{i, 2i} = 1$: for example, when $n= 7$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
For even $n$, it seems that $a_n = n -1$, but I don't know how to prove this. What I know is that $a_n \geq n - 1$ by considering
$$
P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \\ & P' \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $P'$ is the $(n - 1) \times (n - 1)$ permutation matrix that is contructed as above.

> Q2. What is $b_n = \#\{P \in S_n: \text{number of nonzero diagonals in }P = a_n\}$?

Here's a python code with list of $b_n$ for $n \leq 10$:

| $n$ | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $b_n$ | 1 | 2 | 3 | 16 | 15 | 144 | 143 | 2048 | 2025 | 46400 |

````
import itertools

def I(n):
    A = []
    for i in range(n):
        A.append([1 if j == i else 0 for j in range(n)])
    return A

def count_nonzero_diag(m):
    cnt = 0
    n = len(m)
    for k in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if m[j][(k + j) % n] == 1:
                cnt += 1
                break
    return cnt

def max_diag(n):
    A = I(n)
    md = -1
    for m in itertools.permutations(A):
        nd = count_nonzero_diag(m)
        if nd > md:
            md = nd
    return md

def max_diag_mat_num(n):
    cnt = 0
    md = max_diag(n)
    A = I(n)
    for m in itertools.permutations(A):
        nd = count_nonzero_diag(m)
        if nd == md:
            cnt += 1
    return cnt

N = 10
for k in range(1, N + 1):
    print(k, max_diag(k), max_diag_mat_num(k))
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\Zn{\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}}$Q1. We can rephrase the question as follows. We want a bijection $f : \Zn \to \Zn$ such that $\{x : (x, f(x)) = (x, k + x)\} = \emptyset$ for as many values $k$ as possible, i.e., we want $f(x)-x$ to miss as few values as possible. Assume $n$ is even. Then the sum of the values of $f(x)-x$ is zero, whereas the sum of the values of any bijection is $n/2$, so $f(x)-x$ cannot be a bijection, so it must miss at least one value.

Q2. Assume $n$ is odd. Then by the rephrasing above we precisely wish to count bijections $f$ of $\Zn$ such that $f(x)-x$ is a bijection. The counts for small $n$ are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A006717. In https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.05987 it is proved that $b_n \sim e^{-1/2} n!^2 / n^{n-1}$ for large $n$. For even $n$ probably something roughly similar holds.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't realize that this can be though as n queen problem on a toroidal board. Also, regarding Q2, I think it may possible to reduce even $n$ case to odd $n - 1$ or $n + 1$ case (maybe it is possible to construct some map similar to my construction that might give almost bijection).